# Change radio-icon, checkbox color on error

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have used FormBuilderRadioGroup to add a list of radio icon options.
Also, I have used FormBuilderCheckbox to add a checkbox.

On error (validation), both show error in text form beneath the list/text. However, I only wish to change the color of the radio icon/checkbox to red.

How to go about it?

If there is a different widget that I can use, please let me know about it too.

Comment: Can you share your code

Comment: I cannot share the code. I have used the above mentioned widgets and only added list and text tot it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.